# access conditional formatting text that contains based on field

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

How to add expression in MS access to check the current form control if it has text that contains part of a text in another field

> Form Control name: Email
>
> Table Field name: domain

want to make conditional formatting if the Email has text that contains domain

I tried to write the below as expression

```
[Email] like "*" & [mytable]![domain] & "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with quotes:

```
[Email] like "'*" & [domain] & "*'"
```

Comment: Try excluding table name.